# Can I get yesterday's stats using sar command but I have installed sar now

Tags: logs, stat, sar

Can I get yesterday's stats using sar command, I have installed sar now so will I get yesterdays sa logs ? If yes then How ?

I can see today's log :

```
# sar -f /var/log/sa/sa12
Linux 3.14.19-17.43.amzn1.x86_64 (ip-10-179-219-78)     02/12/2016      _x86_64_        (16 CPU)

06:30:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
06:40:01 AM     all      2.40      0.00      0.14      0.24      0.02     97.21
Average:        all      2.40      0.00      0.14      0.24      0.02     97.21
```

But don't have logs for yesterday as I have installed sar now ! So is there any way to get previous day logs ?

```
[root@ADM-PROD-DB-API-1 sa]# ll  /var/log/sa/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9124 Feb 12 06:40 sa12
```

Comment: Can I know why I got down vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  `sar` gathers data and summarises it, but it can't make data up for days where it wasn't installed.  `sar` isn't going to other tools and summarising the data those tools are collecting, `sar` collects it directly, live, at the time.